# I have to find normal subgroups of H in $D_4\times \mathbb Z_2$ of orders 2, 4, and 8.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In $D_4\times\mathbb Z_2$, find normal subgroups $H$ of orders $2$,$4$, and $8$. For each $H$ describe $G/H$.

I know what makes a subgroup normal, but I don't know how to find one. And what would it mean to describe G/H? I could think of is maybe the left cosets and isomorphic subgroups?

Comment: What's $\,D_4\,$ for you? The dihedral group of order $\,8\,$ or the one of order $\,4\,$? Most probably the former, as the later would make things completely trivial.

Comment: it's the one of order 8

Comment: Is it $D_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ or $D_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$? You say both.

Comment: Note, also, these are not "normal subgroups of $H$", these are "normal subgroups $H$." They are "normal subgroups of" $G=D_4\times \mathbb Z_4$ (or $G=D_4\times \mathbb Z_2$, depending on which you meant.)

Comment: It's supposed to be D4 x Z2

Answer (score 1):

We know that $D_4$ is generated by $a$ and $b$ where $a$ is a permutation of length 4.

- $H_1= D_4\times \{0\}$ has order 8.
- $H_2=\{e,a^2b\}\times\{0,1\}$ has order 4.
- $H_3=\{e\}\times\{0,1\}$has order 2.

Answer (score 0):

Hints (be sure you can prove the following):

(1) in a direct product, any normal subgroup of one of the factors is normal in the whole group

(2) Besides the above, check the cases where the subgroup is *not* a subgroup of one of the factors. Sylow subgroups may help here